Why can a song contain chords that are not exactly in its key?
Studying music theory on my own, I try to practice song analysis.
The song "Girl You'll Be a Woman" by Neil Diamond has the following chords:
Gm C F and D#
Now, the feel of the song and heavy usage of Gm chord suggests to me that it should be G minor key.
But chords in Gm are:
Gm Adim Bb Cm Dm Eb(D#) F
And the C from the song doesn't belong to the Gm key (the key has Cm instead).
Is the key of the song different from Gm?

Or a key can have a chord that does not normally belong to it?

You write: And the C from the song doesn't belong to the Gm key (the key has Cm instead). C fits perfectly in Gm that is not limited to natural minor, but can be melodic too. An occuring B (M3) would rather raise doubt in Gm being the key.

We get a lot of questions which seem to stem from the misconception that only certain things are allowed in music, and than anything else must be ‘wrong’ or ‘bad’…  While it's true that some things are frowned on in particular styles if you're trying to be strictly authentic, the fundamental rule is what I call the Rule Of Sounds Good: if it sounds good, then do it!  (Of course, asking why something sounds good or bad is a perfectly valid question.)

EDIT
I'm adding an update, because the OP misidentified the tonic. But, it really does not change the analysis method.
So, we want to look for a dominant to tonic relationship, with importance placed on that progression coinciding with sections. We have that with C7 | F from verse to chorus. This is strong support for analyzing the song in F major.
From there we can look at other chords, often it's a matter of looking at chord that are not simple diatonic chords of the analyzed key. Or, in this case probably a concern about the starting chord.
We have an Eb major chord. If you look about modal chord charts, you will find this chord, along with Gm and F in F mixolydian. But often it is faster to identify chromatic chords from a "stylistic" perspective. A "mixolydian" flat seven chord (ex. F: bVII) is common in rock, pop, and jazz. You can call this a "borrowed" chord. In the key F major a Eb major triad is borrowed from the F mixolydian mode.
The starting chord of Gm may give the impression of a G tonic/ minor type mode, but we really what to see whether that is confirmed, confirmation usually being based on an important cadence, phrase, or section ending. But, in this case we see the harmony continue not to a cadence in G, but in F. The big picture is the harmony outlines Gm C7 F which in Roman numerals is F: ii V7 I, all chord roots by descending fifths, which is a very strong case for the key is F major.
Now, here is the interesting final comment, which underscores the important of the guideline about locating cadences (whether major/minor or modal style) with important phrase and section endings.
Initially I said the song must be in G dorian. Notice that in terms of key signatures that is the same as F major. Both have a key signature of one flat. In that sense the basic, diatonic chords lists are the same. How, do we then distinguish one from the other? By properly locating the tonic pitch. Again, locating the tonic pitch is a matter of identifying the important sectional cadences. In this song it is the verse to chorus section ending where the tonic is confirmed.

Tonic does not necessarily mean key. Minor does not necessarily mean key.
This is the crux of the theory part of your question. But, if you are just beginning to learn music theory that needs to be explained.
Let's assume your ear is correct and the song "centers" around G and a minor quality.
From a single pitch, melodic point of view, we would use the technical term tonic to describe what G is, how the pitch G functions in the song.
From a harmonic perspective, the technical term mode describes what the minor quality is.
So, we have a G tonic and a minor mode. That does not yet tell us whether we are actually in a minor key. The concern being the distinction between minor keys in the major and minor system of keys and modal harmony. Rock, pop, jazz, and many other styles working with modal harmony rather than proper major/minor keys so this distinction comes up all the time in contemporary music.
The quick and dirty explanation about major/minor keys is they need to have a proper dominant chord, a major triad or dominant seventh chord rooted on the fifth scale degree. So, with a G tonic a dominant chord would be a D major triad or D7.
Now we can look at your G minor chord list and the song's chord list.

Gm Adim Bb Cm Dm Eb(D#) F but that needs some fixing... Gm Adim Bb Cm D(7) Eb F#dim would be the simplest list, but we don't need go further into the complexity of minor key harmony.
Gm C F and D# which is better given in all flats as Gm C F Eb

The song doesn't have the D or D7 for a minor key, so it isn't in G minor.
Notice that the pitch E in the chord C is an E natural but in the Eb chord it is, of course, E flat. This means you will not find all these chords in one single list of diatonic chords. That is not a special case, nor a problem, but it requires a little explanation.
Returning to the idea of major/minor keys, we often have major music like C Am D7 G G7 C C7 F Dm G G7 C or minor music like Cm Gm Cm C7 Fm G7 Cm were none of the chromatic chords present a problem with identifying the key. This is because harmony in real music is not restricted to simple, diatonic chord list. (The final ...G7 C and ...G7 Cm parts are the critical key defining moments.) We can apply the same idea to modal harmony.
With a modal list of chords like Gm C F Eb we could say the mode is G dorian with Eb as the chromatic chord, or it could be G aeolian with C as the chromatic chord. There are three ways to make the distinction.

If one chord or the other, C or the Eb is used more frequently than the other, then go with the mode that matches the more frequent chord.
If one of the chords is "structurally" more important, like it is use for the ending of phrases, go with the mode that matches that structurally important chord.
If one of the chords is a "tonal" chord (of the three chords rooted on the tonic, subdominant, or dominant scale degrees), go with the key that matches the tonal chord.

I've thrown a lot of theory terms at you so take your time reviewing my answer. But, this is how you would approach a song's harmony analysis. And when you understand what I have covered you will a lot of the most important stuff about harmony.

"The song doesn't have the D or D7 for a minor key, so it isn't in G minor" sounds like  a 1950s elementary textbook.   We mix and match the various minor modes much more freely now.  I think you're right that the first part isn't in G minor, but that's not why!

@Laurence While the observation may be acceptable, that could theoretically be true even way before the 50s. In some forms, even centuries before that.

:o
I will need to reread this a few times. Thanks for taking time answering the question.

@Laurence, books from the 18th century, and the 19th, 20th, and 21st will say the same, because it is the elementary concept.

@AntonDzodzikov. I added some detail that steps through the analysis, but with the understanding that the key is F major rather than G dorian.

Questions asking about a particular song don't get very far here. However, since there's a theory question at the end, I'll answer.
Songs DO NOT have to adhere to chords which are diatonic to the key they're in. This crops up many times on this site - most likely that will make the question a dupe anyway.
What's happened is chords from the parallel key have been used. So as well as the usual suspects from key Gm, where Cm may be the expected iv, C major, from parallel key G (major) becomes used as the IV instead.
Thus in any song, there are many more chords which could (and are) frequently used.
Incidentally, as key Gm has two flats, your D♯ will be called E♭, one of the 'accidentals' in that key signature.

When two people accidentally say the same thing at once, the custom here is that you want to be the quicker one to say "you buy me a beer". So, you owe me a beer now.

@Divizna - We must have been typing simultaneously! Had I realised, I wouldn't have spoiled your thunder! Awfully sorry, and yes, IOU. It'll have to be a virtual beer though...   although my answer is less abrasive!

No worries, a lot of the time we don't even follow through on it. On the other hand, it isn't particularly rare to hear both people say "you buy me a beer", followed immediately with a "you buy me two" (for the first bumping, and for "you buy me a beer"). Just thought I'd share a fun fact. Anyway, where on earth do these questions pour out of??? Could we plug that portal shut?

@Divizna how else would you earn rating if not for such questions?) Nonetheless, thanks both of you for your replies, it is really helpful to understand the concepts. And, by the way, the question is really more about the theory, the song here is just an example.

@AntonDzodzikov I meant specifically the questions "how dare this tone or chord be in this song". To be honest, I haven't read much of theory. I'd just grab my guitar and some songbook and play whatever I liked. I wasn't told how it should work, I observed in the wild. I think the point where theory betrays you, be it point mass kinematics or this, is when it shows you a simplified model and, instead of admitting that it is a simplified model, it claims that it's the real deal. Then you run into the aspects it left out and you're stumped. Also known as "lies-to-children".

Looks like you are right. I was trying to find logic in all of this. Like, if you use this, then the rules are that. Now it seems like it is more of a bunch of recommendations rather than hard rules. Thanks!

@AntonDzodzikov - so, is that a more accurate answer..?

You've got stuck on the opening section.   Carry on to the chorus (bar 25).   That's clearly  in F major, it's all Gm, C7, F which is ii - V - I in F major.
Can we make sense of the opening section in that context?   I think so.  F works as a tonal centre.  The E♭ chord isn't strictly diatonic, but ♭VII is so common in popular music as to be considered 'honorary diatonic', needing no special justification.


Forget about "chords in a key", will you. Not all chords you find in a song are always made from the tones of the given scale only. A great many songs in G minor will use D or D7 chord as the dominant (those where you'd find a Dmi are in fact in a distinct minority). There's a F#, yes - so what?
Major keys have something similar too. Lots of songs in, say, C major will include C7 - will you find Bb in the scale of C major? Nope. You can also not-so-rarely find a D, E7, Bb or Fmi in C major songs. Using chords with tones out of the scale, and even tones out of the scale in the melody itself, is extremely common.
Go through any songbook and see for yourself.

I think my confusion mainly comes from this (an excerpt from a basic textbook): “The ‘key’ a song is in tells you what scale the ‘raw material’ used in the song comes from. We could define ‘raw material’ as the notes making up any riffs or licks, the notes the singer uses to sing a melody and the notes in the chords played in the song’s chord sequence; basically, all the musical ‘building blocks’ used to create the song.”

@AntonDzodzikov I'm taking issue with the word "any". "Any" riffs or licks, "all" the musical building blocks. Replace it with "most" and then you get something that isn't a lie. The way I think of it, a scale gives you a sort of basic scaffolding. These are the spots that are safe and supported and a song will stand on these for the most part, but it's unlikely it'll stick strictly to them. There very probably will be some tones outside of the scale in the chords, and possibly a few in the melody too. Hope it makes sense.
